# How is Wi-Fi transmitter sends complex number to receiver?

Tags: discrete-signals

I am recently studying physical layer the Wi-Fi (802.11), after doing the FFT, the signal bits are transformed from '0' and '1' to complex numbers, but the complex number is not exist in real life, so my question is:

1. How is transmitter send those complex numbers?
2. What is the transmitter actually send?

Comment: I recommend starting with more basic material, like this free book (linked at the bottom of the page): https://sethares.engr.wisc.edu/telebreak.html

Comment: @MBaz Rick and Bill are great! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is transmitter send those complex numbers?

It doesn't.  As you noted, that's impossible.

> What is the transmitter actually send?

The short answer is that the transmitter takes a baseband signal expressed as inphase/quadrature (I/Q), and modulates the inphase part with $\cos \omega t$ and the quadrature part as $\sin \omega t$.  On the receiving end, the inphase part is demodulated by $\cos \omega t$, and the quadrature part is demodulated by $-\sin \omega t$.

This *acts as if* the I/Q signal were complex with the inphase part being real and the quadrature part being imaginary, and that the transmitter modulated it with $e^{i \omega t}$, and then only transmitted the real part.

It turns out that you can work out all the inphase/quadrature math, very laboriously using only real numbers and trig identities -- or, you can note that if you pretend that your I/Q signal is complex, then you can do all the arithmetic with complex numbers and everything behaves exactly the same.